# makefile: same target and directory name

Tags: make

In my `make` file I have a target `test:`
and `make test` works fine.
But when I also have a subdir called *test*, I get the message:
`make: 'test' is up to date.`
How can I force `make` to ignore the subdir and do the target?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare it as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#index-_002ePHONY). This is supported by GNU make and BSD make.

```
.PHONY: test
test: build
    test/run_them_all
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to avoid this problem using POSIX compliant methods, you may use this Makefile:

```
test: FRC
    some commands

FRC:
```

This will always rebuild `test` under the assumption that no file `FRC` exists.

This method is in use since aprox. 42 years.

The name `FRC` means `Force ReCompile`, but any other non existing filename would do it as well.

Comment: Hello Jörg. Thanks for your suggestion. I was looking for a solution that avoids a clash with any name that a user who would use this makefile could have as filename. So I can never be sure it will be a non-existing one.

Comment: You could select an improbable name or wait until 2021 when the new POSIX standard with .PHONY is out. My maintained version of `SunPro Make` supports `.PHONY` since 2 years. I am not shure when this will apply to the Oracle version as well. AIX make does not support .PHONY at all...

Comment: OK, I think I'll wait:-)